# Обернуть содержимое div в ещё один див при скролле на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, joomla, javascript-events

Есть такой код шапки

```
<header class="header-home">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row scroll">
         <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 logo">Тут логотип</div>
         <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 phone">Тут телефон</div>
         <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 col-md-5 col-lg-6 mobile-menu">Тут ещё контент</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
            <div class="header-content">
               <h1>Свято-Троицкий Ипатьевский<br>мужской монастырь</h1>
               <div class="header-button"><a href="#">Узнать больше</a></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Есть строка с классом `scroll`. При скролле данную строку мне надо сделать фиксированной, а содержимое обернуть ещё в один тег.
Скрипт, который написал:

```
window.onload = function(){
   window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   let scrollDistance = window.scrollY;
   if (document.querySelector('.scroll')) {
      const headerHome = document.querySelector('.scroll');
      let headerHomeHeight = document.querySelector('.scroll').offsetHeight;
      let container = document.querySelector('.header-home .container');
      let content = headerHome.innerHTML;
      if (scrollDistance > 78) {
         headerHome.classList.add('header-home-fixed');
         headerHome.innerHTML = '<div class="row-wrapper">' +content+'</div>';
         container.style.marginTop = 0;
      } else {
         headerHome.classList.remove('header-home-fixed');
         container.style.marginTop = '24px';
      }
   }
});
};
```

Получается, что сейчас при скролле у меня содержимое строки с классом `scroll` постоянно оборачивается дивом с классом `row-wrapper` и создаётся много вложенностей.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка? Необходимо оборачивать один раз при скролле, и возвращать обратно, если шапка возвращается на место

Comment: добавьте проверку, что у элемента все еще нету этого класса)

Comment: так класс как раз добавляется (я про header-home-fixed)

Comment: Проблема в том что у вас переменная `content ` всегда обновлялась при прокрутке страницы и добвляла в себя всё болтше и больше элементов

Comment: Так я и говорю, сделайте проверку. Если класса этого нет - добавляем, а если уже есть - не добавляем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу, надеюсь помог.
Сейчас пойдут комментарий по типу "Ох уж эти любители и их левые коды" и т.д

```js
const headerHome = document.querySelector('.scroll');
let content = headerHome.innerHTML;

window.onload = function(){
   window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   let scrollDistance = window.scrollY;
   if (document.querySelector('.scroll')) {
      let headerHomeHeight = document.querySelector('.scroll').offsetHeight;
      let container = document.querySelector('.header-home .container');
      let divRowWrapper = headerHome.getElementsByClassName('row-wrapper');
      if (scrollDistance > 78 && divRowWrapper.length == 0) {
         headerHome.classList.add('header-home-fixed');
         headerHome.innerHTML = '<div class="row-wrapper">' +content+'</div>';
         container.style.marginTop = 0;
      } else if(scrollDistance < 78) {
         headerHome.classList.remove('header-home-fixed');
         headerHome.innerHTML = content;
         container.style.marginTop = '24px';
      }
   }
});
};
```

```html
<header class="header-home">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row scroll">
         <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 logo">Тут логотип</div>
         <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 phone">Тут телефон</div>
         <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 col-md-5 col-lg-6 mobile-menu">Тут ещё контент</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
            <div class="header-content">
               <h1>Свято-Троицкий Ипатьевский<br>мужской монастырь</h1>
               <div class="header-button"><a href="#">Узнать больше</a></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное) всё заработало!